# How To Get an Ip Address in Asp.Net Mvc by using Entity FrameWork?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I Want to Get The Ip Address In Asp.Net(MVC) By Using the Entity Frame Work
i have no idea about that how get the ip address of client machine when He Post Some Thing on My Site From His Machine...guys if you have any related Solution then post that...Thanks

Comment: Why do you thing that you can somehow get client's IP Address using Entity Framework? There is no direct connection between IP Address and Entitiy Framework, unless you want to get IP Address from DataBase.

Comment: . .think*. . . .

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can't use Entity Framework to obtain the client IP address, you can do so in your MVC controller with the `UserHostAddress` property of the `HttpRequest`

```
namespace Mvc.Controllers
{

    using System;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public class HomeController : ClientController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proper code"? You asked how to obtain the user's IP address and I explained how you can do it. Your user will submit from the view which will hit whatever method you have specified on your controller and you can obtain the IP address as shown in the answer above. Stack Overflow is not a "write my application for me" site. It is a question and answer site. If you need more information I suggest you re-word or amend your question accordingly.